# Splitting, counting and formatting multibyte characters in PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, string, multibyte

I am building an experimental PHP app that processes **poems in Cyrillic UTF-8 characters**. I want to achieve the following:

- Count the occurrences of every character and total counts for categories like "all consonants". It might include special characters and punctuation, as long as I can hide some of them in the output. I work on UTF-8, so I can only use multibyte functions. Using count_chars() is not a possibility :(
- Preserve line breaks and capitalization. I keep multiple copies of the original text with different formatting. They may look redundant, but I want to preserve as much information as possible.
- Change HTML formatting of certain characters based on a condition, e.g. give vowels and consonants different background color, or highlight every occurrence of a chosen character. As far as I understand, first I need to split my string into lines (to preserve the breaks), then turn each of them into an array of 1-character chunks. For the output I would join() lines back. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any ideas on how to apply HTML to array values to solve such problem as mine.

### What I tried

On top of not knowing how to do some things, I encountered some minor problems.  Here's step by step what I do now.

I collect a poem through post method. Poem in English for illustration purposes only.

Text sample:

```
We shall not cease from exploration 
And the end of all our exploring
Will be to arrive where we started
And know the place for the first time.
```

I numbered the steps hoping to make commenting easier.

---

**1. Getting the value with and without tags**

This is how it looks in `htmlentities()` after being submitted through textarea:

```
$string = "We shall not cease from exploration<br /> And the end of all our exploring<br /> Will be to arrive where we started<br /> And know the place for the first time."
```

How I output line breaks:

```
$poem = nl2br($string);
```

Here's a copy without tags:

```
$droptags = strip_tags($poem);
```

---

**2. Counting characters**

This is my rudimentary attempt at `count_chars()` that lacks counting loop(s):

```
$poem2array = preg_split('//u', $droptags, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$unique_characters = array_unique($poem2array);
```

The output is following:

```
(
[0] => W
[1] => e
[2] => 
...
)
```

---

**3. Splitting lines into arrays**

Splitting into lines:

```
$lines = preg_split('<br />', $showtags);
```

My problem here is that the array looks like this:

```
(
[0] => We shall not cease from exploration<
[1] => >
And the end of all our exploring<
[2] => >
Will be to arrive where we started<
[3] => >
And know the place for the first time.
)
```

My attempt to split the text into nested arrays. I know it's broken because I can only get the last line.

```
foreach($lines as $line) {
      $line = preg_split('//u', $line, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    }
```

---

**4. HTML styling**

As for HTML styling of arrays, I have no ideas. My reference arrays would look like this:

```
$vowels = array("a", "e", "i");
$consonants = array("b", "c", "d");

$fontcolor = array("vowels" => "blue",
                "consonants" => "orange");
```

Comment: $lines = preg_split ('/<br[^>]*>/i', $string);  try this for an array without br tags.

Comment: I would be easier if you split this question into multiple posts. I am not sure which part of this is not working properly and which one I should address.

Comment: What do you mean "*This is how it looks in htmlentities()*"?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count the occurrence of vowels and consonants in a text you should count the occurrence of each letter and then check if it is vowel or consonant.

To split a string into an array of characters you should use [`mb_str_split()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-str-split.php). If you are stuck with PHP <= 7.3 then you must use `preg_split('//u', $line, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);`.

You can use [`array_count_values()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values) to reduce the array into a count of letter frequency. Then it is just a matter of counting vowels and consonants separately.

To handle multibyte strings properly you should use [mbstring](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) extension. For example [`mb_strtolower`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower) is a multibyte version of `strtolower()` and [`mb_str_split()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-str-split.php) is the multibyte version of `str_split()`

```
<?php

$poem = <<<'POEM'
We shall not cease from exploration 
And the end of all our exploring
Will be to arrive where we started
And know the place for the first time.
POEM;

$vowels = array("a", "e", "i", "o", "u");
$consonants = array_diff(range('a', 'z'), $vowels); // not necessary to diff because of elseif. Just for demonstration

$letterFrequencyInsesitive = array_count_values(mb_str_split(mb_strtolower($poem)));
$noVowels = 0;
$noConsonants = 0;
foreach ($letterFrequencyInsesitive as $letter => $freq) {
    if (in_array($letter, $vowels, true)) {
        $noVowels += $freq;
    } elseif (in_array($letter, $consonants, true)) {
        $noConsonants += $freq;
    }
}

echo 'Number of vowels: '.$noVowels.PHP_EOL;
echo 'Number of consonants: '.$noConsonants;
```

If you want to format each letter separately then probably the easiest is to wrap each letter in a `<span>` tag and apply a class.

```
$formattedOutput = '';
$fontcolor = array("vowels" => "blue",
    "consonants" => "orange");

foreach (mb_str_split($poem) as $char) {
    $lowercase = mb_strtolower($char);
    if (in_array($lowercase, $vowels, true)) {
        $formattedOutput .= '<span class="'.$fontcolor['vowels'].'">'.$char.'</span>';
    } elseif (in_array($lowercase, $consonants, true)) {
        $formattedOutput .= '<span class="'.$fontcolor['consonants'].'">'.$char.'</span>';
    } else {
        $formattedOutput .= $char;
    }
}

echo nl2br($formattedOutput);
```

Comment: May be useful to give the OP a bit of reference for [the `mbstring` set of string manipulation functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) for their cryllic script.

Comment: @Martin I don't understand why you added that first line. The default encoding is UTF-8. Why would I ever need to add that line?

Comment: To show that as the method to ensure the correct default encoding for the page. The mbstring character set can be set in the PHP.ini and there's no guarentee that `UTF-8` is the default encoding used on the script. The PHP.ini can be set to something else by someone else (shared hosting, for example) and as you have not specified the exact encoding on the `mb_` scripts. It's better to show something that is not needed than to not show something that is needed. `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

2. Counting characters

   ```
   for ($i=0;$i<=strlen($droptags);$i++) 
   $count[$droptags[$i]]++;
   ```
3. Splitting lines into arrays

In this case I had to do a tricky. I had to change the marker from < br /> to another marker, in this case ; otherwise the > will always appear

```
$showtags = "We shall not cease from exploration<br /> And the end of all our exploring<br /> Will be to arrive where we started<br /> And know the place for the first time.";
$showtags = str_replace(";",",",$showtags);
$showtags = str_replace("<br />",";",$showtags);
$lines = preg_split('/;/', $showtags);
foreach($lines as $line) {
    echo "lines= $line<BR>";
}
```

In yoour code I suggest to change the name of variable otherwise it wil mix with the variable $line used in the loop

```
foreach($lines as $line) {
  $lineOut = preg_split('//u', $line, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
}
```